# is node-cron job intervals inclusive of both?

Tags: node-cron

I want to run 2 cron jobs.

**0-7 at 1 hour interval** (i.e. 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
**7-0 at 15 min difference** (7:00 should not be included here as it is include in earlier interval and 00:00 shouldn't be here also since it is included earlier)

Now, what I have done is this:

```
'0 0 0-7 * * *'
```

and for 7-0 job

```
'0 */15 7-0 * * *'
```

The problem as you may have noticed is that at 00:00 both cronjobs will be implemented, which I don't want.

One way can be to start the job at `7:15 - 23:30 for 15 minutes`  but I don't know how to do it.

Any help would be appreciated. 

Thanks